# Gluon GraalVM console

Tags: graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

When compiling to native image and running it now days runs in "javaw" mode.
I would like that the console window to be shown also like when running a Java UI application with "java" command.

How to create a native image so that console window is shown in the background of UI when running it?

Thanks,

Comment: Once you create an installer, when you run via the application desktop shortcut, it is not expected to have a console window. However, if you run your executable directly from a terminal (or even via `mvn gluonfx:nativerun`) you get that "console window", where all the logs printed to it. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I have seen that running the application with maven or gradle the console shown but what I want is that the console is shown in production when the .exe is double clicked on.
Also when running .exe in console no logs are shown.